# Как на winApi сделать кнопку, как справа?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

[image]
(win7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего сделать так:

1. В `stdafx.h` включить вместо `windows.h` файл `afxctl.h`:

   ```
   #include <afxctl.h>
   ```
2. В файле с `WinMain()` написать:

   ```
   #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' \`
   name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' \`
   publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")`
   ```

Еще можно где-нибудь явно задать целевую версию:

```
#ifndef WINVER
#define WINVER 0x0610
#endif
```

Подробнее можно почитать на MSDN в статье «[Enabling Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175.aspx)».